# Errors while converting dataframe to csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

For an automation, I need to convert an excel file to csv along with some modifications in some columns. In one of the column I need to change the time stamp to %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'. Currently I am able to do everything and the change reflects on the dataframe except that when I convert it to csv, the timestamp format changes,

This is the code I have been trying now

```
df=pd.read_excel(file,headers=0,index=False)
print(df.head())
df['Reported On '] = pd.to_datetime(df['Reported On '])
df['Reported On ']= df['Reported On '].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strftime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
df.to_csv(csv_name,index=False)
```

The Reported On column in CSV gives the value :8/10/2017 10:50

While if I convert the dataframe to excel, it gives me the required format.

Is it the problem of csv ?

Comment: after `apply` convert that column into `str` then try `to_csv` it may work for you....

Comment: @MohamedThasinah I doubt that this is the problem. I can not reproduce OPs effect and I have exported to csv while the date column still being of type `object`... BTW tested with pandas 0.23.4 on Python 3.7

Comment: @SpghttCd - I didn't get your point. What's problem in this?

Comment: The result of OPs lambda expression is already a string type. And I tested it but cannot reproduce their error. So converting to string seems to me not the problem here.

Comment: @MohamedThasinah . I tried converting to str -   df['Reported On '] = df['Reported On '].astype(str). It did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Even if I can not reproduce your error, please note that you can define the string representation of dates in a csv-file at the time of writing the file instead of altering your data:

```
df=pd.read_excel(file,headers=0,index=False)
print(df.head())
df['Reported On '] = pd.to_datetime(df['Reported On '])
df.to_csv(csv_name, date_format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', index=False)
```

This is IMO better anyway, because it leaves your dataframe independent from some output format requirements in a computable state.

Comment: Tried this, But the same issue. Has it got something to do with csv?

Comment: You tried this code but in your csv the format is different?? Are you sure you commented your apply/lambda-command away for this test...?

Comment: May I ask you how you are checking the csv-file? Loading in Excel or with a text editor?

Comment: Loading in excel

Comment: Is it the problem?

Comment: I think so, because Excel interprets the data before displaying it. If you want to know what's in a text file, use a text editor.

Comment: Yeah .. thanks for the input @SpghttCd. I have used your approach. It's better and easy.Thanks!